# Rails 4 nested form not creating the objects which it accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to get categories and subcategories working.  So far, I can create categories and add subcategories to them. When I submit the form, the subcategories_attributes send, but no Subcategory records are created.  Please help, I'm pulling my hair out over here, and none of the tutorials seem to be helping.

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :subcategories, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories, :reject_if => lambda {|a| 
   a[:content].blank?}
end
```

**subcategory.rb**

```
class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
end
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
   @categories = Category.all
end

def show
end

def new
   @category = Category.new
   @category.subcategories.build
end

def edit
end

def create
   @category = Category.new(category_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @category.save
       format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully 
       created.' }
       format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @category }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
end

def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @category.update(category_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully 
       updated.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'edit' }
       format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
end

def destroy
   @category.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to categories_url }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name, subcategories_attributes: [:id, :name, 
    :_destroy])
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= nested_form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <% if @category.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@category.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category 
      from being saved:</h2>   
      <ul>
      <% @category.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%f.fields_for :subcategories do |builder|%>
    <p>
      <b>Subcategory</b>
      <%=builder.text_field :name%>
      <%=builder.link_to_remove "Remove"%>
    <p>
  <%end%>
    <p>
      <%=f.link_to_add "Add a Subcategory", :subcategories%>
    </p>    

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Params Hash (on submit):**

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"19FxRnWF1F3BD4QZIkkce4arkOPt/BMkWFw6Z+vpV+8=", "category"=>
  {"name"=>"Test", "subcategories_attributes"=>{"1398706662184"=>{"name"=>"TS1", 
  "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1398706664804"=>{"name"=>"TS2", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, 
  "commit"=>"Create Category"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subcategories_attributes` are sent correctly within your `params` hash BUT `content` attribute is missing in them.

```
"subcategories_attributes"=>{"1398706662184"=>{"name"=>"TS1", 
  "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1398706664804"=>{"name"=>"TS2", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

Notice there is no `content` key passed.
So, all the subcategories records passed in `subcategories_attributes` are **REJECTED** due to the condition you specified in `Category` model:

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories, :reject_if => lambda {|a| 
   a[:content].blank?}
```

Notice `:reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:content].blank?}` part above, this will reject all the records for which `content` is missing.

**UPDATE**

> *when I go to my edit action, the fields don't show up, despite being added to the database as intended (and showing up as such in other
>   forms).*

Set a variable in `edit` and `new` actions as below:

```
def new
 @category = Category.new
 @subcategories = @category.subcategories.build ## Added
end

def edit
  @subcategories = @category.subcategories  ## Added
end
```

Update the `fields_for` in `edit` form as below:

```
<%= f.fields_for :subcategories, @subcategories do |builder|%>
```

Comment: So should I use 

    lambda {|a| a[:name].blank?}

instead?

I'm pretty new to lambdas, wasn't sure if :content was a built-in symbol for "stuff here."

Comment: Yes, you can. Its just a check on another attribute. As you are passing `:name` field for subcategories in `subcategories_attributes`, it would resolve your issue. `subcategories` would be saved successfully.

Comment: One other question- when I go to my edit action, the fields don't show up, despite being added to the database as intended (and showing up as such in other forms).  I'd like to be able to remove subcategories if necessary from the edit action.  Sorry if I'm being a bother...

Comment: See the UPDATE section in the answer.

Comment: **EDIT** I was mistaken, the code still doesn't work.  It returns an "undefined method `model_name' for #<Class:0x000000053b6410>" error on the edit action, pointing at the <%f.fields_for @subcategories, :subcategories do |builder|%> line.

Comment: Check the updated `fields_for` in answer. Also `=` was missing in `<%= fields_for .....%>` , you would need that to render output of `fields_for` in view.

Comment: That equals sign fixed everything!  Nice catch!  Really appreciate the help!